# I can't ssh on localhost at a certain port on os x

Tags: ssh, osx, openssh

Here are basics information:

```
$ which ssh
/opt/local/bin/ssh
```

It's like that because I'm using MacPorts and it did install there.
I did the `sudo port load openssh`

When doing a netstat -an | grep LISTEN on reboot. I have this:

```
tcp4       0      0  *.2222                 *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0  *.2222                 *.*                    LISTEN
tcp46      0      0  *.5900                 *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  *.88                   *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0  *.88                   *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  *.631                  *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0  *.631                  *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  *.22                   *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0  *.22                   *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  *.139                  *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  *.445                  *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  *.548                  *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0  *.548                  *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.631          *.*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0  ::1.631                *.*                    LISTEN
```

then here are the results of nmap:

```
-pierre@evian.local ~ nmap -p 22 localhost                                                                                                                   0 --15:23--

Starting Nmap 5.50 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2011-02-10 15:24 CET
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000083s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.19 seconds
-pierre@evian.local ~ nmap -p 2222 localhost                                                                                                                 0 --15:24--

Starting Nmap 5.50 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2011-02-10 15:25 CET
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000072s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
2222/tcp open  EtherNet/IP-1

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.05 seconds
```

Now what happen when I try to ssh on localhost

```
-pierre@evian.local ~ ssh localhost                                                  0 --15:30--
Connection closed by 127.0.0.1
```

When specifying the 2222 port.

```
-pierre@evian.local ~ ssh localhost -p 2222                                        255 --15:31--
Last login: Thu Feb 10 15:18:00 2011 from localhost
```

Succeed! The reason: I found it in the sshd_config file on the /opt/local/etc/ location. port 2222 here the file:

```
-pierre@evian.local ~ cat /opt/local/etc/ssh/sshd_config | less                      0 --15:29--

#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.81 2009/10/08 14:03:41 markus Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

Port 2222
```

So I decided to change the port in that file to 22

relaunch the service with unload/load as follow:

```
-pierre@evian.local /opt/local/etc/ssh ssh localhost -p 2222                         0 --15:35--
Last login: Thu Feb 10 15:32:15 2011 from localhost
-pierre@evian.local ~ sudo port unload openssh                                       0 --15:35--
-pierre@evian.local ~ sudo port load openssh                                         0 --15:36--
-pierre@evian.local ~ ssh localhost -p 2222                                          0 --15:36--
ssh: connect to host localhost port 2222: Connection refused
```

Well, I'm feeling lucky and I try ssh localhost

```
-pierre@evian.local ~ ssh localhost                                                255 --15:36--
Connection closed by 127.0.0.1
```

No such a thing as luck I suppose. Here is a -vv of the command:

```
-pierre@evian.local ~ ssh -vv localhost                                            255 --15:37--
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0c 2 Dec 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /opt/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug1: identity file /Users/pierre/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/pierre/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug1: identity file /Users/pierre/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /Users/pierre/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 1.99, remote software version OpenSSH_5.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 127/256
debug2: bits set: 520/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/pierre/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 534/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/pierre/.ssh/id_rsa (0x10030e540)
debug2: key: /Users/pierre/.ssh/id_dsa (0x10031dcf0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/pierre/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
Connection closed by 127.0.0.1
```

What do you think?

Comment: Very nicely asked question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OS X comes with `sshd` already. It's running if you enable "Remote Login" in System Preferences under Sharing.

If all you want to do is make it listen on a non-default port, the trick is as follows:

1. Open `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist` in your favorite text editor.
2. Find the `SockServiceName` key.
3. Change the string value to something like `ssh-alt`, then save the plist file.
4. Add an entry for `ssh-alt` to the `/etc/services` file.
5. Go into the Sharing preference pane and toggle the "Remote Login" checkbox off and back on. You'll find that the native `sshd` is now listening on the other port.

You'd think you could avoid all that by editing `/etc/sshd_config`, but you'd be wrong. The native `sshd` pays attention to the plist file, only.

Comment: Well, it did work. I owe you one. Thank you for your clear description and time!

Comment: The ports for the *sshd* that is bundled with Mac OS X can not be configured through `/etc/sshd_config` because the bundled *sshd* is launched in “inetd mode”. In this mode *sshd* expects stdin and stdout to be already connected to the client, so it has no say over what port or protocols are used to listen for and accept clients. `/etc/sshd_config` is still effective for configuring other aspects of the default *sshd*. The plist file for the MacPorts *sshd* does not use “inetd mode”, so the ports for that *sshd* can be configured in its configuration file (`/opt/local/etc/ssh/sshd_config`).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Chris. I didn't mean to imply that the native `sshd` ignored everything in `sshd_config`, only the `Port` setting. I like to turn off `PermitRootLogin` and `PasswordAuthentication` in mine on any host I've got port-forwarded to the Internet. Using a different port number is part of that securing process. It's merely "security through obscurity", but it does cut down on a whole lot of bot attack traffic nevertheless.